# Creating photo albums

Tags: iphone, xcode, photo

How do you create a photo album coding an iphone app that appears in the photo albums that sync to iPhoto?

I can read and write media using the various classes (eg UiImagepickerController)no problems. Just wondering if that extends to being able to create albums also.

Comment: It's possible from iOS 5.
Please check this [tutorial](http://www.touch-code-magazine.com/ios5-saving-photos-in-custom-photo-album-category-for-download/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you can't do this. You can save images only in the Camera Role album

Comment: This seems rather limiting to keeping many videos :S I guess capacity will increase over time in any case. thanks for the heads up.